# Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory insert update false

Tags: java, hibernate

Table Client
Name="clients"

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="clientObj", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private List<BookedRoom> bookedRooms;
```

And table Booked Room

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
private BigInteger id;

@Column(name="accommodation")
private BigInteger accommodation;

@Column(name="account")
private BigInteger account;

@Column(length=40)
private String clients;

@Column(name="clients_id", length=40)
private String clientsId;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="clients", nullable=false)
@JsonBackReference 
private Client clientObj;

@Column(name="rooms_no")
private byte roomsNo;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="room", nullable=false)
@JsonBackReference 
private AccommodationRoom accommodationRoom;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="bed_preference")
@JsonBackReference 
private BedPreference bedPreferenceBean;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="booking", nullable=false)
@JsonBackReference 
private Booking bookingBean;
```

And error:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping
>   for entity: ba.go2balkan.pojo.BookedRoom column: clients (should be
>   mapped with insert="false" update="false")
>        [java]   at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:709)
>        [java]   at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkPropertyColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:731)
>        [java]   at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:753)
>        [java]   at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:506)
>        [java]   at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:270)
>        [java]   at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1358)
>        [java]   at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1849)
>        [java]   at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
>        [java]   ... 34 more

And don't tell me to insert (insertable="false", updateble="false"). Because when I insert that than I can not read data from database or anything else. That's not solution.

Comment: It says repeated column means two column mapped with the same name . can you check

Comment: if you actually want two field mapping the same column then you have to use insertable updatable false on one of the two mappings or hibernate can't tell which one to use... but then again we can't tell unless you post the whole entities

Comment: I v eddited post. I copied my whole bookedRoom.java file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have

```
@Column(length=40)
private String clients;
```

and

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="clients", nullable=false)
@JsonBackReference 
private Client clientObj;
```

that are trying to map the same db column (if you don't specify column name then hibernate will use field name for column mapping)...

Either give a different name to the first if it's actually another column, use `insertable=false, updatable= false` on the non association mapping `String clients` or remove that meaningless field altogether